Access data on my google drive using service account
I can't read the files that I saved on "Google Drive" using the code that You can see below.

I've yet enabled the "Google Drive API" in the GCP project.
I've yet created the "service account" and in the "API/Service Detail"(https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com) a can see it.
I've yet generate the json file with the credentials of the "service account".

All seems fine and the the code don't get errors, but don't find the files that are on Google Drive, why?
Where is my fault?
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

service_account_json_key = '****sa-key-jsonfile****.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=service_account_json_key, scopes=SCOPES)


def search_file():
    """Search file in drive location"""
    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
        files = []
        page_token = None
        while True:
            # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
            response = (
                service.files()
                .list(
                    # q="mimeType='image/jpeg'",
                    spaces="drive",
                    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
                    pageToken=page_token,
                )
                .execute()
            )
            for file in response.get("files", []):
                # Process change
                print(f'Found file: {file.get("name")}, {file.get("id")}')
            files.extend(response.get("files", []))
            page_token = response.get("nextPageToken", None)
            if page_token is None:
                break

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        files = None

    return files


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ret = search_file()
    print(ret)



Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation, in your script, it seems that the files are retrieved from the drive of the service account using the service account. In this case, does the drive of the service account have some files? The drive of the service account is different from your Google Drive. I'm worried about it. If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Hi Tanaike,
What i wish, is use a service account to access to my data in my Google Drive.
I have a GCP project associated to my personal gmail account (everyone can have it, is enough go to "https://console.cloud.google.com/") On my project I've activate Google Drive API, created a service account and enabled it with  Google Drive API indeed i can see it in "Service Accounts" of "https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/credentials".
What am I missing?

I finally found how to do that:
I must share the directory that have my files to the email of the service account!
